# Find matching property value in deeply nested objects: firestore v9 and javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore document data like this:

```
UsersData: {
  a1234sdffsdf: {
    avatarUrl: 'xxxxxx',
    id: 'qwe234234',
    name: 'larry',
    status: 'online'
  },
  u1ty4sdff09k: {
    avatarUrl: 'xxxxxx',
    id: 'abc123456',
    name: 'stephen',
    status: 'online'
  }
}
```

I want to loop through two objects(`a1234sdffsdf` and `u1ty4sdff09k`) to find the `id` property that matches user id and update the status to `'offline'`. How do I implement this with firebase v9?

```
collection: chatrooms
document: randomid
data: UsersData

const chatroomQuery = query(collection(db, 'chatrooms', where(loop through UsersData and find id, '==', user.id)
updateDoc(chatroomQuery, { status: 'offline' })
```

Can anyone help me with this? Your help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

There really is no way to do the query as you have it laid out.  You are attempting a query of "documents that have the field `UserData.${some_id}`".  But Firestore queries are about values in fields, not about the existence of fields.

One option would be to create a separate field within each document of just the user IDs in that document (let's call it `userIds`) and querying against that field.

So a document could look like:

```js
{
  UsersData: {
    a1234sdffsdf: {
      avatarUrl: 'xxxxxx',
      id: 'qwe234234',
      name: 'larry',
      status: 'online'
    },
    u1ty4sdff09k: {
      avatarUrl: 'xxxxxx',
      id: 'abc123456',
      name: 'stephen',
      status: 'online'
    }
  },
  userIds: ['a1234sdffsdf', 'u1ty4sdff09k']
}
```

and then the query would be:

```js
const chatroomQuery = query(collection(db, 'chatrooms',
                            where('userIds', 'array-contains', user.id))

const chatroomSnap = await getDocs(chatroomQuery);
if (chatroomSnap.size === 1) {
  const chatroomRef = chatroomSnap.docs[0].ref;
  await updateDoc(chatroomRef, ........);
} else if (chatroomSnap.size > 1) {
  console.log("Got more than one chatroom....now what?");
} else {
  console.log("no chat rooms found");
}
```

You might want to reconsider your data structure for `UserData` as well.  It is a bit awkward to work with in terms of having variable key names...which is technically doable but makes for some less-than-straightforward coding.

Note: your original code was not properly getting a DocumentReference to pass to `updateDoc()`.  You were passing a Query to it which will not work.